# How to pass a list of Object in Webclient get request call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

How to send List object as parameter to get controller

EX:

```
@GetMapping("/demo")
public List<Student> m1(List<Employee> account)
{

}

public Employee
{
 String id;
 String name;
}
```

**How to call webclient**:
I tried like

```
Employee e = new Employee("1","tarun");
Employee e1 = new Employee("2","run");
List<Employee> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(e);
a.add(e1);
webclient
.get()
.uri(x->x.path("/demo")
.queryParam("account",a)
.build())
.accept(json)
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(new parameterizedtypereference<List<Student>>(){});
```

When I tried like above getting error, Can anyone please help me how can I call the above m1 method using webclient, I need to pass list for the m1 method.`

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you make sure to include the necessary dependencies for Spring **WebFlux** and **WebClient** in your project.

If you want to send List object as a parameter to a @GetMapping controller method using WebClient, you can use the `bodyValue()`.

First you `Employee` class should be serializable

```
public class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    // Constructor, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

There is little change in your controller method as well.

```
@GetMapping("/demo")
public List<Student> m1(@RequestBody List<Employee> account) {
    // Your implementation
}
```

and This how you have to call this method using WebClient,

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

// ...

Employee e = new Employee("1", "tarun");
Employee e1 = new Employee("2", "run");
List<Employee> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(e);
a.add(e1);

List<Student> result = WebClient.create()
        .post()
        .uri("/demo")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .bodyValue(a)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Student.class)
        .collectList()
        .block(); // block() is used here for simplicity, consider using subscribe() in a real application

// 'result' now contains the response from the server
```